# Can "Become" perfectly substitute for "get" in this context?

Tags: word-difference

Below is an [explanation](https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-apprenticeship-and-internship.html) about internship versus apprenticeship.
I would like to ask if **become** can be also used perfectly there instead of **get** in bold. I know there are several posts in ELL covering become vs get, but I really wonder about this specific context.

> On the other hand, an internship is for undergraduate students where
>   they learn specific skills and work experience required in a
>   particular field or job, which may or may not be paid. People **get**
>   puzzled when they are asked to distinguish the two, but the fact is
>   that there exists a fine line of difference between apprenticeship and
>   internship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "become". "People get puzzled" is less formal; "people become puzzled" is formal or standard.

Comment: Absolutely. But here, I would say: are puzzled, in fact. There is no real reason to use either get or become. We're puzzled when [etc.] or by x.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for the comment. Do you recommend using ***be puzzled** over **get/become puzzled** because it is simpler? Or is there any other reason?

Comment: I recommend it because it is more elegant: _get_ is colloquial, and _become_ is heavier. The simplest is "be puzzled" about something.